# `ORDER BY` before `GROUP BY` in a request with INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-order-by, inner-join

Initially I need to build a query fetching `sites` from one table ordered by date of newest `article` (`articles` placed in the separate table).

I build the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `sites`
INNER JOIN `articles` ON `articles`.`site_id` = `sites`.`id`
ORDER BY `articles`.`date` DESC
GROUP BY `sites`.`id`
```

I supposed that `SELECT` and `INNER JOIN` will fetch all *posts* and associate a *site* to each one, than `ORDER BY` will order the result by descending of *post* date than `GROUP BY` will take the very first post for each *site* and I will get the needed result.

But I'm receiving MySQL error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY`sites`.`id`LIMIT 0, 30' at line 7`

If I place `GROUP BY` **before** `ORDER BY` statement the query is working but it will not give me the **newest** post for each site. Instead the result will be sorted **after** the grouping which is not the thing I need (actually I could prefer to order in another way after grouping).

I read several pretty similar questions but they all related to the data stored in a single table making it possible to use `MAX` and `MIN` functions.

What should I do to implement what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came to the solution.

First of all I changed the main query from queering from `sites` table to queering from `articles`. Next I added the MAX(`date`) column to the result.

So the resulting query implementing the thing I need is the following:

```
  SELECT `sites`.`url`,MAX(`articles`.`date`) AS `last_article_date`
  FROM `articles`
  INNER JOIN `sites` ON `sites`.`id` = `article`.`site_id`
  GROUP BY `site_id`
  ORDER BY `last_article_date` ASC
```

Thanks to all of you for giving me hints and right search directions!

Comment: It does not give other columns aligned with 'last_article_date'

Comment: This helped me! `GROUP BY` AND `MAX` together is the key I guess

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a subquery / derived-table / inline-view or a self-exclusion join, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.*, a1.*
FROM `sites` s
    INNER JOIN `articles` a1 ON a1.`site_id` = s.`id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `articles` a2 ON a2.`site_id` = a1.`site_id`
        AND a2.`date` > a1.`date`
WHERE 
    a2.`site_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    a1.`date` DESC
```

The principle is that you select the sites for which there is no article date greater than any other article date.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the sql to the following syntax -

```html
SELECT `articles`.`article_name`,'sites'.'id','articles'.'site_id'
FROM `sites`,'articles'
WHERE `articles`.`site_id` = `sites`.`id`
ORDER BY 'sites'.'id', `articles`.`date` DESC;
```

Do something like this in the select statement. Group by function demands that all fields to be grouped. Hence usage of * is not possible.

Comment: You are selecting rows from `sites` and filtering results by `articles`. Isn't something missing ?

Comment: **#1054 - Unknown column 'articles.site_id' in 'where clause** which is pretty expected as MySQL shouldn't know what is `articles` table.

Comment: Please select required fields from both tables instead of giving a *. then do the group by action to all those fields starting from sites.id. Just give it a try. i currently dont have mysql here, so cant try here.

Comment: @DileepKK could you edit you original answer to make it more clear what `select from both table` mean. I suppose it's a wrong approach.

Comment: I'm not sure for 100% but I really believe that it is a wrong approach as you are multiplying two tables. If I'd have 1000 sites and 1 000 000 posts it will result in 1 000 000 000 rows (before WHERE clause can be applied).

Comment: hoW MANY articles do you really want? Say if you want total 50 articles from all the sites, just add LIMIT 50 after ORDER BY CLAUSE. Also you can use SELECT TOP 50 'ARTICLES'.'ARTICLE_NAME',... . Also to fetch 10 percent of all the results use SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT 'ARTICLES'.'ARTICLE_NAME'...

Comment: Quantities of 1000 by 1 mio was taken just to outline that this approach is defective. I`m not going to have anything like this quantities but I have to think about server productivity and build effective queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (  SELECT `S.<col1>`, `S.<col2>`, `A.<col1>`,`A.<col2>`,
                           ROW_NUMBER ()
                           OVER (PARTITION BY `SITES`.`ID`
                                 ORDER BY `SITES`.`ID` DESC)
                              RID
                      FROM `SITES` `S`,`ARTICLES` `A`
                      WHERE `ARTICLES`.`SITE_ID` = `SITES`.`ID`
                  )
           WHERE RID = 1;
```

Can you try this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this query looks too complicated for **me** :( I'd better use a queries I could understand.